# optidef model name

Tags: math-mode, optidef

After some researches I was not able to find any reference to this feature.

Is it possible to add a single name, say (P), to an optidef-defined model?
The following is an image of what I'm trying to achieve

[image: optidef model example]

It is not necessary that the (P) is aligned to the objective function row, it might be wherever but it is important it is on the left.

And this is the code to produce it but without the red (P).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[short]{optidef}

\begin{document}

\begin{mini!}
  {w,u}{f(w)+ R(w+6x)}{}{}\tag{1}
  \addConstraint{g(w_k)+h(w_k)}{=0,}{k=0,\ldots,N-1}\tag{2} 
  \addConstraint{l(w_k)}{=5u,\quad}{k=0,\ldots,N-1}\tag{3}
\end{mini!}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can abuse the fourth argument:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[short]{optidef}

\begin{document}

\begin{mini!}
  {w,u}{f(w)+ R(w+6x)}{}{\text{(P)}\quad}\tag{1}
  \addConstraint{g(w_k)+h(w_k)}{=0,}{k=0,\ldots,N-1}\tag{2}
  \addConstraint{l(w_k)}{=5u,\quad}{k=0,\ldots,N-1}\tag{3}
\end{mini!}

\end{document}
```

[image]