# Align a multi-line equation in cases environment

Tags: equations, cases

I have an equation:
[image]

generated by the following code snippet:

```
Secondly, instead of simultaneously minimizing the mean and standard deviation of the objective(s),
another type of formulation of robust optimization considers the standard deviation as the constraint:

\begin{flalign}\label{eq:robust-optimization-2}
    \text{Type II:}
    \begin{cases}
        \text{find}       &\vect{x} \\
        \text{minimizing} &\mu\left\{f_{i}(\vect{x}, \vect{p})\right\} (i = 1, ...\, , n_{\text{objectives}}) \\
        \text{subject to} &\sigma\left\{f_{i}(\vect{x}, \vect{p})\right\} \leq \sigma_{i}^{\text{crit}} (i = 1, ...\, , n_{\text{objectives}}) \\
                          &L_{j}(\vect{x}, \vect{p}) \leq 0 (j = 1, ...\, , n_{\text{constraints}}) \\
                          &\vect{x}^{-} \leq \vect{x} \leq \vect{x}^{+}
    \end{cases}
\end{flalign}

Thirdly, as previously discussed, in the robust design optimization problem as formulated by
```

How do I modify my code such that the following 2 requirements (brown and green color) are satisfied while other things remain as they are?
[image]

Comment: This seems to be duplicate to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/636303/alignment-in-the-cases-environment. AQNd please provide complete document, a MWE, which reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just use an `equation` environment and nest `aligned` in cases:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}
\let\vect = \mathbf

\begin{document}

Secondly, instead of simultaneously minimizing the mean and standard deviation of the objective(s),
another type of formulation of robust optimization considers the standard deviation as the constraint:

\begin{equation}\label{eq:robust-optimization-2}
    \text{Type II:}
    \begin{cases}\begin{aligned}
         & \text{find} & &\vect{x} \\
         & \text{minimizing} & &\mu\left\{f_{i}(\vect{x}, \vect{p})\right\} & & (i = 1, ...\, , n_{\text{objectives}}) \\
         & \text{subject to} & & \sigma\left\{f_{i}(\vect{x}, \vect{p})\right\} \leq \sigma_{i}^{\text{crit}} & & (i = 1, ...\, , n_{\text{objectives}}) \\
                    & & &L_{j}(\vect{x}, \vect{p}) \leq 0 & & (j = 1, ...\, , n_{\text{constraints}}) \\
                    & & &\vect{x}^{-} \leq \vect{x} \leq \vect{x}^{+}
    \end{aligned}\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Thirdly, as previously discussed, in the robust design optimization problem as formulated by

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With `fleqn` environment defined in the `nccmath` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{fleqn}
\begin{align}\label{eq:robust-optimization-2}
\text{Type II:}
    \left\{\begin{aligned}
        \text{find}       &&& \bm{x} \\
        \text{minimizing} &&& \mu\left\{f_{i}(\bm{x}, \bm{p})\right\}
                            &&   (i = 1, ...\, , n_{\text{objectives}}) \\
        \text{subject to} &&& \sigma\left\{f_{i}(\bm{x}, \bm{p})\right\} \leq \sigma_{i}^{\text{crit}}
                            &&   (i = 1, ...\, , n_{\text{objectives}}) \\
                          &&& L_{j}(\bm{x}, \bm{p}) \leq 0
                            &&   (j = 1, ...\, , n_{\text{constraints}}) \\
                          &&&\bm{x}^{-} \leq \bm{x} \leq \bm{x}^{+}
                            &&
        \end{aligned}\right.
\end{align}
\end{fleqn}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines show text area border)